# Override Laravel From Address on SendsPasswordResetEmails trait

Tags: php, laravel, email

How can I override the forgot password email from address field?

I'm using the `SendsPasswordResetEmails trait`.

It seems to be using the `.env mail-from configuration`

here is the trait vendor code [SendsPasswordResetEmail Trait](https://github.com/guiwoda/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/SendsPasswordResetEmails.php)

`sendResetLinkEmail method` seems to be where the magic happens but i cannot determine how to override the mail send from the broker where is this function? `sendResetLink`

Comment: Can you explain, what you are trying to achieve, based on that I may able to give some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the trait its code and past it in the `PasswordBroker` class to overwrite it if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to edit `broker()` just override `sendResetLinkEmail()` in your `ForgetPasswordController`. Then override `$request->mail` entry.

Anyway, the function you are looking for is at "\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker.php" => sendResetLink()

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is set

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=sender@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Sender
```

in .env file and it should work fine, you do not need to override `sendResetLinkEmail method`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a two methods I can think of that will achieve what you want.

1) In AppServiceProvider:

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    config()->set('mail.from.address', 'YOUR FROM ADDRESS HERE');
}
```

2) In Controller.php:

```php
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
      config()->set('mail.from.address', 'YOUR FROM ADDRESS HERE');
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!